# Clarification on Oracle DB Audit Configuration - Settings

Tags: oracle12c, audit-trail, audit-logging, database-security

I have read information regarding audit configuration of in Oracle 12c, however, looking for some clarification. Some information I read led to some confusion.

The audit config I am reviewing has the following settings:

audit_sys_operations
TRUE

audit_file_dest
D:\ORACLE\ADMIN\HOSTNAME\ADUMP

audit_trail
DB

SQL>      spool off;

My understanding is that the adump directory is the default location on the database. Also, the AUDIT_TRAIL initialization parameter is set to DB, which I understand directs all audit records to the database audit trail. We have a Syslog configured that collects event logs from various servers, including this particular database server; however, I do not believe it is collecting database audit trail. My concern here is that the logs are written to the DB, and not to an external location. Wouldn’t having the AUDIT_TRAIL set to =OS be more appropriate, security wise? If the DB becomes inaccessible, so will the DB logs?  I want to make sure my understanding is correct. I am not the DBA.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration the "adump" location will contain logs generated by "sysdba" activity, but not the general user audit trail. Setting audit_trail=os will send everything to the OS, *but* beginning with Oracle 12c and moving forward Oracle has implemented a "unified audit trail" in which everything is consolidated into a common database view and "OS" is no longer an option. Your configuration is the original "core" audit architecture, which is still supported (for now) for backwards compatibility. Ultimately you should move towards unified auditing and use some other tool to export your audit data to syslog or some other consolidation service. Check this link for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/recommended-and-best-practices-complete-upgrading-oracle-database.html#GUID-EB285325-CA65-41B4-BE58-D3F69CFED789